# SQL: What is wrong with this create table?

Tags: sql, mysql

What is wrong with the sql statement below?
Database is mysql. The statement is generated by my function.

Parser claims there's something wrong near 'IF' but I must be blind...

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS statements (
  'symbol' VARCHAR(10),
  'statement' VARCHAR(20),
  'frq' VARCHAR(2),
  'date' DATETIME,
  'account' VARCHAR(200),
  'value' BIGINT,
  PRIMARY KEY('symbol', 'statement', 'date')
);
```

Comment: Specifically which version of which database engine are you asking for?

Comment: You may find this URL helpful in your attempt to create a table. 

https://www.mysqltutorial.net/mysql-create-table/     you seem to be missing an engine identity.

Comment: MySQL errors always include the phrase **Check the manual for your MySQL version for**. Did you do that? If you Google **MySQL X.x documentation**, replacing the **X.x** with your MySQL version number, you can find that documentation very easily, and you'd have had the answer to this in less time than it took you to post the question here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot have column names within single quotes in a create statement. Instead, use -

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS statements
(
    symbol VARCHAR(10)
  , statement VARCHAR(20)
  , frq VARCHAR(2)
  , date DATETIME
  , account VARCHAR(200)
  , value BIGINT
  , PRIMARY KEY (
                  symbol
                , statement
                , date
              )
);
```